# How to transfer columns into rows using Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

result of my query is

| new_person | upd_person |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 23 |

And i would like to look like

| persons | count |
| --- | --- |
| new_person | 10 |
| upd_person | 23 |

Thank you

Comment: This is called pivoting. Converting rows to columns is done using PIVOT. Converting columns to rows can be done with UNPIVOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transpose columns into rows in Oracle, you can use the `UNPIVOT` operation.

```sql
SELECT person_type AS persons, count
FROM (
    SELECT new_person, upd_person
    FROM your_table
) 
UNPIVOT (
    count FOR person_type IN (new_person AS 'new_person', upd_person AS 'upd_person')
);
```